# $x^n = y^n \Leftrightarrow x = y$ for all real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have to prove a simple property but i have doubts about a property used in the demonstration.
I've to prove that
$\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert^{2} =\lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} - (\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}})^{2}$
where x is the vectorial product.

I decide to use a formula given to me as definition and to go from there: $\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert =\lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \sin(\theta)$

since $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ both sides are positive, so i square them both, obtaining: $\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert^{2}=\lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} \sin^{2}(\theta)$.

Then since $\sin^{2}(\theta) = 1 - \cos^{2}(\theta)$, i can replace the $\sin^{2}({\theta})$: $\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert^{2}=\lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} (1 - \cos^{2}(\theta))$ becomes $\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert^{2}=\lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} - \lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2}(\cos^2{\theta})$.

Now, i use another formula that was given to me, which is: $\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}} = \lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \cos(\theta)$.

And here's the problem: as far as i know i can raise to the power of 2 both sides if and only if we're dealing with positive numbers. That is $x = y \iff x^n = y^n$ is valid only if $x,y\in \Bbb R^{+}$. Now the vectors'norm is positive by definition while the cosine can be negative for $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ so how come the solution says to use this property anyway?

It goes: $\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}} = \lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \cos(\theta)$, which then becomes $(\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}})^{2} = \lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} \cos^{2}(\theta)$ and gets replaced in the other formula, obtaining what we wanted: $\lVert\vec{u}$ x $\vec{v}\rVert^{2} =\lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} - (\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}})^{2}$.

I struggle to understand why it's ok to raise to the power of 2 both sides of $\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}} = \lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \cos(\theta)$. After all, if it was true that $x = y \iff x^n = y^n$ is valid in $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then i can say that $(5)^{2} = (-5)^{2} \iff 5 = -5$ which is obviously false.

P.S. i'm an undergraduate

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $x^n=y^n$ does imply $x=y$, but if $n$ is even, then $x^n=y^n$ only implies $|x|=|y|$.

Comment: But you’re only using the direction that is valid. If $x=y$, then $x^2=y^2$.

Comment: Squaring both sides of an equation is always acceptable.  It's just not reversible, which in this case just means we cannot tell the sign of $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ from the squared equation. (The concern you have might be that squaring can introduce extraneous solutions, but that doesn't matter here)

Comment: It's valid to say that if $x,y$ are non-negative reals then $x^n = y^n \iff x=y$.  That's usually the definition of $x^{\frac 1n}$.  As you are dealing only with non-negative values that's okay.  Even if we are dealing with complex number $x^n=y^n \iff |x| = |y|$ is valid.

Comment: @fleablood Your last biconditional was overextended into being false.  What is true is $x=y\implies x^n=y^n$ and $x^n=y^n \implies |x|=|y|$.

Comment: How is... uh... yeah.  Dope slap.  I guess I meant $|x| = |y| \iff |x^n| = |y^n|$ ... but now I'm back to simply the non-neg reals.  I guess I meant what you said $x^n=y^n\implies |x| =|y|$ and $x=y\implies x^n=y^n$.... actually I guess what I meant was $x=y\cdot\text{nth root of unity}\iff x^n = y^n$ but ... we're getting into the not practical to specify territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realize that [assuming $X,Y$ are complex numbers and $n$ is an integer] the statements (a) $X=Y \implies X^n=Y^n$ and (b) $X^n=Y^n \implies X=Y$ are two different statements. The former statement (a) is always true, the latter statement (b) [which is the converse of statment (a)] is not always true.

In fact, let $f$ be any function whose domain and range is in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $X$ and $Y$ be in the domain of $f$. Then $X=Y$ $\implies$ $f(X)=f(Y)$ is always true. However, $f(X)=f(Y)$ does not guarantee $X=Y$, for general functions $f$. To add something else to this however, $f(X)=f(Y)$ *does* imply $X=Y$ if $f$ is an invertible function. The function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; $f(X)=X^n$; $n$ an *odd* integer, qualifies.

So getting back to your example: It is true that $X=Y \implies X^2 = Y^2$. So setting $X=\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}}$ and $Y=\lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \cos(\theta)$, it follows that $X=Y$
$\implies$ $X^2=Y^2$. Thus,
$$\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}}=\lVert \vec{u}\rVert\lVert \vec{v}\rVert \cos(\theta)$$
$$ \implies (\mathrm{\vec{u}}\cdot\mathrm{\vec{v}})^{2} = \lVert \vec{u}\rVert^{2}\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^{2} \cos^{2}(\theta),$$
as your textbook claimed.